# For-loop Alternative to do 2D & 3D Matrix Multiplication in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

For discussions' sake, I have a 2D matrix (A) of shape 2x2 and a 3D matrix (B) of shape 2x2x10. I am currently looping over the last axis of matrix B, and constructing the full matrix one sub-matrix at a time.

```
A = np.random.random((2,2))
B = np.random.random((2,2,10))
C = np.zeros_like(B)
for i in range(B.shape[-1]):
    C[:,:,i] = A @ B[:, :, i]
```

In reality, my matrices are much larger than this and I know there must be something more efficient than a for loop. I have looked at a couple of prior questions where the solution involves using np.tensordot or np.einsum, but frankly, I don't think I am using it right.

```
# Basic
C_basic = A @ B
print(f'Basic {np.allclose(C, C_basic)}')  # False

# Einsum
C_einsum = np.einsum('ij, jik-> ijk', A, B)
print(f'np.einsum {np.allclose(C, C_einsum)}')  # False

# Newaxis
C_newaxis = A[np.newaxis, ...] @ B
print(f'np.newaxis {np.allclose(C, C_newaxis)}')  # False

# Swapaxes
C_swapaxes = A @ np.swapaxes(B, 0, 2)
C_swapaxes = np.swapaxes(C_swapaxes, 0, 2)
print(f'np.swapaxes {np.allclose(C, C_swapaxes)}')  # False
```

Comment: If your `B` was (10,2,2), then `A@B` should work, with a (10,2,2) result.  It might be easier to test if `A` was (2,3) and `B` was (3,4,10).  That is, make the axis that is summed distinctive (here 3).  In your last case you need another `swapaxes`.  In the `einsum`

Comment: The `einsum` expression should be 'ij,jkl->ikl` - with the dot sum on `j`, the rest of the dot `i` and `k`, and `l` as the batch (that's going along for the ride).  The `@` works with 'i,j,k'.  The batch dimension has to be first.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few possibilities:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.random((2,2))
B = np.random.random((2,2,10))
C = np.zeros_like(B)
for i in range(B.shape[-1]):
    C[:,:,i] = A @ B[:, :, i]

Cs = [np.einsum('ij,jkl',A,B),
      np.tensordot(A,B,((-1,),(0,))),
      (A@B.reshape(len(B),-1)).reshape(-1,*B.shape[1:]),
      np.moveaxis(A@np.moveaxis(B,-1,0),0,-1),
      (A@B.transpose(2,0,1)).transpose(1,2,0),
      np.inner(B.T,A).T,
      (B.T@A.T).T]

print([np.allclose(C,Ci) for Ci in Cs])
```

prints:

```
[True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
```

These are, however, not 100% equivalent: For example. the first three are C-contiguous, the last two Fortran and the middle two neither.

You can inspect using:

```
for Ci in Cs:
    print(Ci.flags)
```